# Share an audio file from an url

Tags: java, android

I want to share an audio file from an url (the url is audio.getUrl())
I`m trying to download the file fristly and then share it but it close the app when i try in my smartphone.
Can you show me any other method?
Please help.

```
 DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(audio.getUrl());
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/sdcard/download/", "audio.mp3");
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            compartirAudio.setType("audio/*");
            compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("/sdcard/download/audio.mp3"));
            v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Share"));
```

Comment: If it closes your app, there's likely a crash.  Have you checked your crash logs?

Comment: It show me that don't have write permissions, do you know how to do it?

Comment: This should have everything you need: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Okey, thanks it works. But trying this i've noticed one problem: In some audios, i don't know wky, but when sharing with whatsapp it tell me that this file its not compatible. All the audios are in .mp3, but some let me share and some don't let me. Do you know any possible answer?

Comment: That could be any of a number of things, from invalid tags to size constraints, to invalid internal audio codec formats, etc.  So, I know many possible answers, but too many to really be helpful :) You'd need to maybe do some comparison between mp3s that work and those that don't and see what's different.

Comment: i don't see anything differente, only when i download it the audios which not work are not recognized as an mp3 file, but when i click them it give the option of play with the player. When i download and save it into the phone storage, have i to put the name like "audioname.mp3" or just "audioname"?